# Separating an array from Google Sheets in email templates

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email

I'm trying to create an email sender from a Google Sheet using Apps Script, but is not formatting like I want, and still have a bit of manual work that has to be done before sending out.

The Sheet is currently set up to flag problems, and I want my email to grab instances of the problem and send out. I currently have it set up to loop through each row and when it finds one of the problems, pushes to an array which is what I want. But I need each instance on its own row.

```
for (let j=0;j<arrayProblem.length;j++){

    arrayReport.push([j+1]+')' + ' '+ arrayProblem[j] +  ' This problem was found on ' +arrayHeader[j]+' Please review this resource for more information on how to correct the issue: '+ arrayLink[j]+'.');
```

};

The email then just takes the whole arrayReport for the email body. So I still have to manually go through and separate out each instance.

Is there a way to have the email automatically split each problem onto its own row?

Comment: Add a new line `\n` to each item pushed to the array.  And I would change `[j+1]` to `(j+1)`

Comment: I have tried that and the email is still putting it in a single line. But when I print to the console, it's showing them on separate lines there.

Comment: Seems you need to use HTML markup when sending an email from Apps Script.
Check Gmail functions there for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution. The comment about needing to go into the HTML for the email was the right track.

Added the "\n" to the array push, then in the HTML where the template tag is being pulled I wrapped it in a whitespace span:

```
<span style="white-space: pre;"><?= problem ?></span>
```

That seemed to do the trick, and it's working exactly as wanted now!